# ExtJS 5 - Add a key/value to Object in Mixed Collection

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have a mixed Collection Object, which have 5 items in it. Based on certain condition now i would like to add a new set of key/value pair to one of the item.

```
items: Array[5]
  0: Object$extCollectionIndex: 2
  align: "left"
  dataIndex: "reportCode"
  hidden: false
  hideable: true
  sortable: true
  sorted: false
  text: "Report Code"
  width: 74
  xtype: null
  __proto__: Object
  1: Object
  2: Object
  3: Object
```

It it achievable in Mixed Collection ?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not 100% clear,  if you meant something else, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

A MixedCollection has a method `add`,  so it is quite basic to accomplish what you are looking for :

Suppose the variable `collection` contains your Mixed collection,  this is all you need.

```
collection.add('key', 'value')
```